# Visual Basic 6.0 ToolTipText Multiline

Tags: loops, vb6

I need help on how to do looping for this function.I get this coding from http://www.vbcode.com/Asp/showsn.asp?theID=6906 .

My problem is, I wwanted to do multi line tooltiptext for 6 different images, can all this be simplified using for..next loop ?

Thanks.

```
'A Multi-Line ToolTip Example
'
'by: Christopher D. Manns


Public Function MrToolTip(MyControl As Control, MyString As String)

   TxtToolTip.Visible = True

   If MyControl.Left + MyControl.Width + TxtToolTip.Width < Me.Width - MyControl.Left + TxtToolTip.Width Then
      TxtToolTip.Move MyControl.Left + MyControl.Width, MyControl.Top
   Else
      TxtToolTip.Move MyControl.Left - TxtToolTip.Width, MyControl.Top
   End If
   TxtToolTip.Text = MyString

End Function

Private Function MrToolTipReset()
'Hide the tool tip text box.

   TxtToolTip.Visible = False
   TxtToolTip.Text = ""

End Function
'------ Everything below an Example Using MrToolTip -------

Private Sub imgIsland_MouseMove(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
'An Example of how to call MrToolTip, you can call MrToolTip from
'MouseMove Event of any control.

   MrToolTip imgIsland, "This is an example of " & _
   "MrToolTip. Can't beat a Multi-Line Tool Tip"

End Sub

Private Sub Form_MouseMove(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
'Unless you want a tooltip for the form, clear it and hide.
   MrToolTipReset
End Sub
Private Sub TxtToolTip_MouseMove(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
'User has moved from active control.
  MrToolTipReset
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't know your sample, bu I know the BEST ever ToolTipText (from PSC):

"VB ExTooltip by MArio Flores"
http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=59810&lngWId=1

Comment: Thank You, Giorgio Brausi. It does help a lot.